# "FDR<0.05", or "FDR 0.05"?

Tags: reporting, false-discovery-rate

I thought FDR is a *threshold* that we set, so we should speak about it without a `<` (or `≤`) sign. For example, in a manuscript I wrote something like "30 genes were found significantly associated (FDR 0.05)". But my co-authors changed it to "FDR<0.05" – is it really the more correct form?

Comment: I would agree with you, but the inequality should be $\le$.

Comment: thanks, you're right that by definition it should be rather `≤` than `<`. My point was about not using `<` at all, i.e. saying "FDR 0.05" or "FDR=0.05"

Comment: Equals would be wrong, since you didn't prove that. You don't know how many of your tests are in reality a negative, so at best you can keep the FDR *below* this threshold.

Comment: @FransRodenburg Banjamini & Hochberg would appear to disagree, and use $\le Q_{e}$ and $\le q^{*}$(where $Q_{e}$ and $q^{*}$ are their notation for the FDR) in Benjamini, Y. and Hochberg, Y. (1995). [Controlling the False Discovery Rate: A Practical and Powerful Approach to Multiple Testing](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~doerge/BIOINFORM.D/FALL06/Benjamini%20and%20Y%20FDR.pdf). *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society*. Series B (Methodological), 57(1):289–300.

Comment: @Alexis, yes sorry I wasn't clear. I meant that FDR$=0.05$, as in the comment above mine would be wrong.

Comment: @FransRodenburg Ah! I totally misunderstood. Carry on! :)